# Trigger OnCreate of Activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using Xamarin to make an Android App.
I created a fragment include a listview.
When I click the item I want to create a new activity.

```
    private void LvOnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs itemClickEventArgs)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(SteWaveActivity));
        Activity.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Above codes are all in a fragment class.
But method **onCreate** of the activity class **SteWaveActivity** isn't executed.
How should I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: why not    var intent = new Intent(Activity, SteWaveActivity.class);

Comment: Thanks for you reading my question.Now I know the reason.Just my stupid mistake.